# Adding types to properties in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

I was following this https://www.udemy.com/angular-4-front-to-back/ tutorial series and I'm bit confused.

It says(16th video) we can't define type of a property and assign it to another type of property(value).

**e.g :**
This is ok and getting compiled (According to the tutorial)

```
age : number = 15;
```

But this is a violation and give an compile error (According to the tutorial)

```
age : number = "15";
```

But here I tried `age:number="fifteen"`and it doesn't give an error and it's compiling without any issue. Why is that ?

**Here I've given number type to age**
[image: Here I've given number type to age]

**Here it compiles without any error**
[image: Here it compiles without any error]

**This is the error according to the tutorial**
[image: This is the error according to the tutorial]

**EDIT**

The code

```
@Component({
  selector : 'sandbox',
  template : `
            <h1>Hello {{ name }} is {{ age }} years old `;
})

export class SandboxComponent{
    name : string = "John Doe";
    age : number = "fifteen";
    hasChildren : boolean = true;
    numbersArray : number[] = [1,2,5,"Hello World"];
    stringsArray : string[] = ["UoM","UoJ","UoC","UoP"];

    constructor(){

    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your `age:number="fifteen"` ? it's seems like different `string` and `number` type when use `quote or not.

Comment: @RachChen in the 1st image I've highlighted that age:number="fifteen" .
Sorry I didn't get the last part. What do u mean when use ` quote or not ?

Comment: Both `Atom` and `VSCode` are encountered `Highlight disabled` randomly .If you set `"15"` then it would be classify to `string`.you remove the quote and it would be number like `15`

Comment: @RachChen yea, So here I've defined age as number type but assigned the value of a string "fifteen". There should be an error, right ?

Comment: The red circle is covering up some of the punctuation which may affect it. Can you just post the code by itself, preferably not a screenshot?

Comment: @BrendanWhiting added the source code

Comment: @BrendanWhiting not only that, u can see in the same screenshot, I've used "Hello World" in numbersArray which is an array of type number

Comment: You also have a stray semicolon at the end of your template. Other than that I dunno, I would just restart the editor. Maybe something got snagged with the typescript compiler, and maybe the version you're looking at in the browser is an old version of the app before you made the change. That's all I can think of.

Comment: Of course, it [gives an error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20SandboxComponent%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%20%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22John%20Doe%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%20%3A%20number%20%3D%20%22fifteen%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hasChildren%20%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20numbersArray%20%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C5%2C%22Hello%20World%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20stringsArray%20%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%22UoM%22%2C%22UoJ%22%2C%22UoC%22%2C%22UoP%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: Thanks @BrendanWhiting fixed it. The thing is my view doesn't update in the browser. It shows the error ( about the ; in the template) in the cmd which I ran ng serve . But the view doesn't update according to the changes I make on the editor.

Comment: @estus yea, I know it should. I was trying to figure out why doesn't it gives me an erro

Comment: Did you try restarting your code editor?

Comment: yes @BrendanWhiting , and tried running the app again. both didn't help

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what's wrong then